# How to supress a specific scalastyle rule in IDEA?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scalastyle

I want to suppress `no.finalize` rule of ScalaStyle only for one particular class.

I figured that one approach to suppress IntelliJ IDEA's inspection is to add following comment at the beginning of the class:

`//noinspection ScalaStyle`

However, this will suppress all ScalaStyle rules for that particular class. I want to suppress only one rule selectively.

Note that I have already tried scalastyle's suppression approach which is to use 
`// scalastyle:off no.finalize`. However, it is not honored by IntelliJ IDEA.

I am using IDEA version 2018.2.5 (Community Edition).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
// scalastyle:off <rule id>
```

In your case:

```
// scalastyle:off no.finalize
```

List of ids: http://www.scalastyle.org/rules-dev.html

*The solution works for IDEA 2019.3. Better to update the IDE with Scala plugin*

Comment: As I mentioned, I already tried it. (By mistake I added :on in the quersion but in code I have added it with :off)

Comment: Maybe try it on different line. Make a couple of guesses.

Comment: @vatsalmevada That solution works for me in IDEA 2019.3. Try to update your IDE with Scala plugin

Comment: I agree with @vatsalmevada , I was using the 2018 IDEA until a couple of days ago, but 2019 version offers quite a few upgrades. I didn't regret it.

Comment: Thanks @Duelist. Working for me with IDEA 2019.

Comment: @vatsalmevada I approved the edit , can you mark it as working solution. Thanks.